# Java Testing if a variable equals a value in the array if not print -1

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I need to see when a given variable value in an array is first occurred and once occurred change that variable to the number when it first occurs, and if it does not occur than change the value to -1. 
For example 32 appears first in the array so it should print 1 but 100 never appears in the array so it should print -1 but how do I make a second if statement in my loop so that the variable will be -1 but it test the original value to find it appears. Sorry if I did not explain it well enough.

here is the code for the loop and the first if statement

```
  public static int occurrence(int[] a) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int occurrence = scnr.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] == occurrence)
            occurrence = i + 1;

    return occurrence;
```

Comment: Not following.  Please show sample data, and expected output.

Comment: the data is just a bunch of different values but the expected output is the index when the value you input in the scanner first appears in the array, so if 2 was the value put in the scanner than it would find when 2 first appeared and print saying if first appeared as the 5th index then it would print 5, but if it never appeared I want it to print -1, most likely i assume this would use a second if statement. Hopefully that helps. Sorry for not giving the data, there just is alot of numbers, and I hope it can be understood without it.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK library comes with an Arrays class just for things like this.

First, import the class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Now all you have to do is this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, occurrence));
```

And that's basically it. The "binarySearch()" method takes two parameters, those being the name of the array you're referencing (a), and the value you are searching for in that array (occurrence). It then returns the index of the value. If the value is not found in the array, it returns -1.

Comment: Note that `Arrays#binarySearch` requires a sorted array to operate properly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is also an Arrays.sort(array) method as well that uses a bubble sorting method to order values from least-greatest. If the person wants their array sorted before searching for a value, they could add:

Comment: ..."Arrays.sort(a);" before searching for the value of occurrence. (Sorry for the double post, I accidentally pressed enter while typing the previous comment).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this.  Try to separate your input code (scanner) from the function logic.  That will make the occurrence method reusable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int data[] = { 2,5,7};
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputValue = scnr.nextInt();

        int index = occurrence( data, inputValue);
        System.out.println("value at index: " + index);
    }

     //
     // find first match, then exit the loop if found.
     //
     public static int occurrence(int[] a, int inputValue) {
         int result = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (a[i] == inputValue) {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }

            return result;
     }

}
```